# How to exclude awk text block that has specific condition of strings in the block

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to exclude a text-blocks when a certain condition occurs.

The files have this layout:

```
- name: Sedan
  tags:
  - DIGIT
  - ABC
  - DEF
  - YES
- name: Combi
  tags:
  - DIGIT
  - ABC
  - DEF
  - NO
- nane: SUV
  tags:
  - DIGIT
  - DEF
  - YES
- nane: OTHER
  tags:
  - DIGIT
  - ABC
  - YES
```

The condition is: `ABC && !DEF`
So, print only the text-block that will have only `ABC` in the block.

It should give me this printout:

```
- nane: OTHER
  tags:
  - DIGIT
  - ABC
  - YES
```

My first try was something like that:

```
awk '/^- name:/ { if (found && value) {print value} found=value="" } { value=(value?value ORS:"")$0 } /ABC/ && !/DEF/ { found=1 } END { if (found && value) { print value } }' file
```

But the above try prints every text-block with both patterns!

Both below solutions are working and here it is how I am using it to do this for multiple files:

```
for i in `find /home/ -mindepth 1 -type f ! -empty`; do ln=`awk -v RS='(^|\n)- ' '/- ABC(\n|$)/ && !/- DEF(\n|$)/ {printf "- %s\n", $0}' $i; printf $i`; echo -e $ln"\n" | sed -n -e 's/^.*file: //p' | grep txt ; done
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`, you can split file into records using first `-` in each block:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|\n)- ' '/- ABC/ && !/- DEF/ {printf "- %s", $0}' file

- nane: OTHER
  tags:
  - DIGIT
  - ABC
  - YES
```

Or to make it more precise:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|\n)- ' '
/- ABC(\n|$)/ && !/- DEF(\n|$)/ {printf "- %s", $0}
' file
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I will update also my question on how I will use it in a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm normally not a fan of multiple instances of `awk/sed/grep` in a pipeline, but this problems seems suited to it.  First, insert blank lines as record separators.  Then filter.  Then remove the blank lines:

```
 awk '/^-/{print ""} 1' input | awk '/ABC/ && !/DEF/' RS= | sed '/^$/d'
```

Some versions of `awk` allow multi-character RS, but this pipeline seems simple enough to use with those implementations of `awk` that do not support that extension.

But it seems that a better solution would be to convert the yaml to json, then filter with `jq`, and then convert back to yaml.